# Looping through tiles, only get can get the index of the first tile

Tags: java, input

I've created a very basic tile system in which I wanted to be able to get the current tile the mouse was hovering over, this works great for the first tile created, but other than that I'm looking at nothing.

Here's the code to setup and draw the tiles, and the "Currently hovering" text.

```
private static final int TILE_WIDTH = 64;
private static final int TILE_HEIGHT = 64;

private static Tile[][] gridTiles = new Tile[(int)Math.ceil(Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / TILE_HEIGHT)][(int)Math.ceil(Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / TILE_WIDTH)];

public CombatGrid() {} // Cannot instantiate this class

static {        
    // Rows
    for(int r = 0; r < gridTiles.length; r++) {
        // Columns
        for(int c = 0; c < gridTiles[0].length; c++) {
            gridTiles[r][c] = new Tile((c * TILE_WIDTH), (r * TILE_HEIGHT), TILE_WIDTH, TILE_HEIGHT);
            System.out.println("New tile("+r+","+c+") was created at: x: " + (c * TILE_WIDTH) + " y: " + (r * TILE_HEIGHT));
        }
    }
}

public static void draw(Batch batch) {
    for(int r = 0; r < gridTiles.length; r++) {
        for(int c = 0; c < gridTiles[0].length; c++) {
            gridTiles[r][c].draw(batch);
            if(gridTiles[r][c].hovering(Gdx.input.getX(), Gdx.input.getY())) {
                Assets.defaultFont.draw(batch, "Current hover index("+r+","+c+")", Client.TOP_LEFT_X + 10, Client.TOP_LEFT_Y - 30);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The text only shows when I'm overing over Tile[0][0]

Here's the hovering method from the Tile class

```
public boolean hovering(float x, float y) {
    if((x > this.x) && (x < this.width)) {
        if((y > this.y) && (y < this.height)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

The mouse input that I'm passing to hovering is correct as-well, and when I move out of the 0,0 tiles bounds, it no longer draws.

Also, I'm debugging my mouse position

```
Assets.defaultFont.draw(batch, "Curret mouse X: " + Gdx.input.getX() + " Y: " + Gdx.input.getY(), Client.TOP_LEFT_X + 10, Client.TOP_LEFT_Y - 10);
```

and it shows that the math I've set up is correct, or atleast should be unless I missed something

Now, i know all the tiles are being greated and placed correctly, because of the `Debugging Statement` in the static initializer which shows:

```
New tile(0,0) was created at: x: 0 y: 0
New tile(0,1) was created at: x: 64 y: 0
New tile(0,2) was created at: x: 128 y: 0
New tile(0,3) was created at: x: 192 y: 0
New tile(0,4) was created at: x: 256 y: 0
New tile(0,5) was created at: x: 320 y: 0
New tile(0,6) was created at: x: 384 y: 0
New tile(0,7) was created at: x: 448 y: 0
New tile(0,8) was created at: x: 512 y: 0
New tile(0,9) was created at: x: 576 y: 0
New tile(0,10) was created at: x: 640 y: 0
New tile(0,11) was created at: x: 704 y: 0
New tile(0,12) was created at: x: 768 y: 0
New tile(0,13) was created at: x: 832 y: 0
New tile(0,14) was created at: x: 896 y: 0
New tile(0,15) was created at: x: 960 y: 0
New tile(0,16) was created at: x: 1024 y: 0
New tile(0,17) was created at: x: 1088 y: 0
New tile(1,0) was created at: x: 0 y: 64
New tile(1,1) was created at: x: 64 y: 64
New tile(1,2) was created at: x: 128 y: 64
New tile(1,3) was created at: x: 192 y: 64
New tile(1,4) was created at: x: 256 y: 64
New tile(1,5) was created at: x: 320 y: 64
New tile(1,6) was created at: x: 384 y: 64
New tile(1,7) was created at: x: 448 y: 64
New tile(1,8) was created at: x: 512 y: 64
New tile(1,9) was created at: x: 576 y: 64
New tile(1,10) was created at: x: 640 y: 64
New tile(1,11) was created at: x: 704 y: 64
New tile(1,12) was created at: x: 768 y: 64
New tile(1,13) was created at: x: 832 y: 64
New tile(1,14) was created at: x: 896 y: 64
New tile(1,15) was created at: x: 960 y: 64
New tile(1,16) was created at: x: 1024 y: 64
New tile(1,17) was created at: x: 1088 y: 64
New tile(2,0) was created at: x: 0 y: 128
New tile(2,1) was created at: x: 64 y: 128
New tile(2,2) was created at: x: 128 y: 128
New tile(2,3) was created at: x: 192 y: 128
New tile(2,4) was created at: x: 256 y: 128
New tile(2,5) was created at: x: 320 y: 128
New tile(2,6) was created at: x: 384 y: 128
New tile(2,7) was created at: x: 448 y: 128
New tile(2,8) was created at: x: 512 y: 128
New tile(2,9) was created at: x: 576 y: 128
New tile(2,10) was created at: x: 640 y: 128
New tile(2,11) was created at: x: 704 y: 128
New tile(2,12) was created at: x: 768 y: 128
New tile(2,13) was created at: x: 832 y: 128
New tile(2,14) was created at: x: 896 y: 128
New tile(2,15) was created at: x: 960 y: 128
New tile(2,16) was created at: x: 1024 y: 128
New tile(2,17) was created at: x: 1088 y: 128
New tile(3,0) was created at: x: 0 y: 192
New tile(3,1) was created at: x: 64 y: 192
New tile(3,2) was created at: x: 128 y: 192
New tile(3,3) was created at: x: 192 y: 192
New tile(3,4) was created at: x: 256 y: 192
New tile(3,5) was created at: x: 320 y: 192
New tile(3,6) was created at: x: 384 y: 192
New tile(3,7) was created at: x: 448 y: 192
New tile(3,8) was created at: x: 512 y: 192
New tile(3,9) was created at: x: 576 y: 192
New tile(3,10) was created at: x: 640 y: 192
New tile(3,11) was created at: x: 704 y: 192
New tile(3,12) was created at: x: 768 y: 192
New tile(3,13) was created at: x: 832 y: 192
New tile(3,14) was created at: x: 896 y: 192
New tile(3,15) was created at: x: 960 y: 192
New tile(3,16) was created at: x: 1024 y: 192
New tile(3,17) was created at: x: 1088 y: 192
New tile(4,0) was created at: x: 0 y: 256
New tile(4,1) was created at: x: 64 y: 256
New tile(4,2) was created at: x: 128 y: 256
New tile(4,3) was created at: x: 192 y: 256
New tile(4,4) was created at: x: 256 y: 256
New tile(4,5) was created at: x: 320 y: 256
New tile(4,6) was created at: x: 384 y: 256
New tile(4,7) was created at: x: 448 y: 256
New tile(4,8) was created at: x: 512 y: 256
New tile(4,9) was created at: x: 576 y: 256
New tile(4,10) was created at: x: 640 y: 256
New tile(4,11) was created at: x: 704 y: 256
New tile(4,12) was created at: x: 768 y: 256
New tile(4,13) was created at: x: 832 y: 256
New tile(4,14) was created at: x: 896 y: 256
New tile(4,15) was created at: x: 960 y: 256
New tile(4,16) was created at: x: 1024 y: 256
New tile(4,17) was created at: x: 1088 y: 256
New tile(5,0) was created at: x: 0 y: 320
New tile(5,1) was created at: x: 64 y: 320
New tile(5,2) was created at: x: 128 y: 320
New tile(5,3) was created at: x: 192 y: 320
New tile(5,4) was created at: x: 256 y: 320
New tile(5,5) was created at: x: 320 y: 320
New tile(5,6) was created at: x: 384 y: 320
New tile(5,7) was created at: x: 448 y: 320
New tile(5,8) was created at: x: 512 y: 320
New tile(5,9) was created at: x: 576 y: 320
New tile(5,10) was created at: x: 640 y: 320
New tile(5,11) was created at: x: 704 y: 320
New tile(5,12) was created at: x: 768 y: 320
New tile(5,13) was created at: x: 832 y: 320
New tile(5,14) was created at: x: 896 y: 320
New tile(5,15) was created at: x: 960 y: 320
New tile(5,16) was created at: x: 1024 y: 320
New tile(5,17) was created at: x: 1088 y: 320
New tile(6,0) was created at: x: 0 y: 384
New tile(6,1) was created at: x: 64 y: 384
New tile(6,2) was created at: x: 128 y: 384
New tile(6,3) was created at: x: 192 y: 384
New tile(6,4) was created at: x: 256 y: 384
New tile(6,5) was created at: x: 320 y: 384
New tile(6,6) was created at: x: 384 y: 384
New tile(6,7) was created at: x: 448 y: 384
New tile(6,8) was created at: x: 512 y: 384
New tile(6,9) was created at: x: 576 y: 384
New tile(6,10) was created at: x: 640 y: 384
New tile(6,11) was created at: x: 704 y: 384
New tile(6,12) was created at: x: 768 y: 384
New tile(6,13) was created at: x: 832 y: 384
New tile(6,14) was created at: x: 896 y: 384
New tile(6,15) was created at: x: 960 y: 384
New tile(6,16) was created at: x: 1024 y: 384
New tile(6,17) was created at: x: 1088 y: 384
New tile(7,0) was created at: x: 0 y: 448
New tile(7,1) was created at: x: 64 y: 448
New tile(7,2) was created at: x: 128 y: 448
New tile(7,3) was created at: x: 192 y: 448
New tile(7,4) was created at: x: 256 y: 448
New tile(7,5) was created at: x: 320 y: 448
New tile(7,6) was created at: x: 384 y: 448
New tile(7,7) was created at: x: 448 y: 448
New tile(7,8) was created at: x: 512 y: 448
New tile(7,9) was created at: x: 576 y: 448
New tile(7,10) was created at: x: 640 y: 448
New tile(7,11) was created at: x: 704 y: 448
New tile(7,12) was created at: x: 768 y: 448
New tile(7,13) was created at: x: 832 y: 448
New tile(7,14) was created at: x: 896 y: 448
New tile(7,15) was created at: x: 960 y: 448
New tile(7,16) was created at: x: 1024 y: 448
New tile(7,17) was created at: x: 1088 y: 448
New tile(8,0) was created at: x: 0 y: 512
New tile(8,1) was created at: x: 64 y: 512
New tile(8,2) was created at: x: 128 y: 512
New tile(8,3) was created at: x: 192 y: 512
New tile(8,4) was created at: x: 256 y: 512
New tile(8,5) was created at: x: 320 y: 512
New tile(8,6) was created at: x: 384 y: 512
New tile(8,7) was created at: x: 448 y: 512
New tile(8,8) was created at: x: 512 y: 512
New tile(8,9) was created at: x: 576 y: 512
New tile(8,10) was created at: x: 640 y: 512
New tile(8,11) was created at: x: 704 y: 512
New tile(8,12) was created at: x: 768 y: 512
New tile(8,13) was created at: x: 832 y: 512
New tile(8,14) was created at: x: 896 y: 512
New tile(8,15) was created at: x: 960 y: 512
New tile(8,16) was created at: x: 1024 y: 512
New tile(8,17) was created at: x: 1088 y: 512
New tile(9,0) was created at: x: 0 y: 576
New tile(9,1) was created at: x: 64 y: 576
New tile(9,2) was created at: x: 128 y: 576
New tile(9,3) was created at: x: 192 y: 576
New tile(9,4) was created at: x: 256 y: 576
New tile(9,5) was created at: x: 320 y: 576
New tile(9,6) was created at: x: 384 y: 576
New tile(9,7) was created at: x: 448 y: 576
New tile(9,8) was created at: x: 512 y: 576
New tile(9,9) was created at: x: 576 y: 576
New tile(9,10) was created at: x: 640 y: 576
New tile(9,11) was created at: x: 704 y: 576
New tile(9,12) was created at: x: 768 y: 576
New tile(9,13) was created at: x: 832 y: 576
New tile(9,14) was created at: x: 896 y: 576
New tile(9,15) was created at: x: 960 y: 576
New tile(9,16) was created at: x: 1024 y: 576
New tile(9,17) was created at: x: 1088 y: 576
New tile(10,0) was created at: x: 0 y: 640
New tile(10,1) was created at: x: 64 y: 640
New tile(10,2) was created at: x: 128 y: 640
New tile(10,3) was created at: x: 192 y: 640
New tile(10,4) was created at: x: 256 y: 640
New tile(10,5) was created at: x: 320 y: 640
New tile(10,6) was created at: x: 384 y: 640
New tile(10,7) was created at: x: 448 y: 640
New tile(10,8) was created at: x: 512 y: 640
New tile(10,9) was created at: x: 576 y: 640
New tile(10,10) was created at: x: 640 y: 640
New tile(10,11) was created at: x: 704 y: 640
New tile(10,12) was created at: x: 768 y: 640
New tile(10,13) was created at: x: 832 y: 640
New tile(10,14) was created at: x: 896 y: 640
New tile(10,15) was created at: x: 960 y: 640
New tile(10,16) was created at: x: 1024 y: 640
New tile(10,17) was created at: x: 1088 y: 640
New tile(11,0) was created at: x: 0 y: 704
New tile(11,1) was created at: x: 64 y: 704
New tile(11,2) was created at: x: 128 y: 704
New tile(11,3) was created at: x: 192 y: 704
New tile(11,4) was created at: x: 256 y: 704
New tile(11,5) was created at: x: 320 y: 704
New tile(11,6) was created at: x: 384 y: 704
New tile(11,7) was created at: x: 448 y: 704
New tile(11,8) was created at: x: 512 y: 704
New tile(11,9) was created at: x: 576 y: 704
New tile(11,10) was created at: x: 640 y: 704
New tile(11,11) was created at: x: 704 y: 704
New tile(11,12) was created at: x: 768 y: 704
New tile(11,13) was created at: x: 832 y: 704
New tile(11,14) was created at: x: 896 y: 704
New tile(11,15) was created at: x: 960 y: 704
New tile(11,16) was created at: x: 1024 y: 704
New tile(11,17) was created at: x: 1088 y: 704
```

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Answer (score 1):

Try this;

```
public boolean hovering(float x, float y) {
    if((x > this.x) && (x < this.x + this.width)) {
        if((y > this.y) && (y < this.y + this.height)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```